# Java send XML String

Tags: java, xml, soap

Hi I need send a request with a string XML, I'm trying this way:

```
final String SOAP_ACTION     = "http://tempuri.org/Search";
final String METHOD_NAME     = "Search";
final String NAME_SPACE      = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String URL             = "https://www.url.com/xxx/xxx.asmx?wsdl";
String       XML             = "<data><id>"+ paramId +"</id><phone>"+ paramPhone +"</phone></data>";
SoapObject request           = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("", XML); //I don't know how to pass it here
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet                             = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE             httpTransport   = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object res = envelope.getResponse();
        if (res instanceof SoapPrimitive ) {
            return (((SoapPrimitive) res).toString());
        }
        return String.valueOf(res);
    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException ex) { }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> SoapFault - faultcode:
>   'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@16050315

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *FYI:* You don't send the SOAP message to a `?wsdl` URL. The `?wsdl` URL is used to retrieve the WSDL of the webservice endpoint.

Comment: You're receiving an error message from the server, saying that the server encountered a NullPointerException (or equivalent). You should check server code and/or log file for more detail.

Comment: *FYI:* Building XML using string concatenation is a real bad idea, unless you handle XML escaping yourself. You'd end up with bad XML if someone entered a `<` in their phone number. Sure, phone number validation logic might guard against that, but you can't always rely on that.

Comment: ok I subtracted the ?wsdl but how can I pass the data inside the <data></data> ????

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you could use wsimport to create the SOAP stubs for you. That makes it much easier. The stubs do already some conversion tasks for you.

If a String parameter contains XML elements, they are URL-Encoded, at least the < is encoded ad &lt; and the > as &gt;
In your situation it should help if you do this on your string parameters just  with a simple string replacement:

```
XML = XML.replace("<", "&lt;");
XML = XML.replace(">", "&gt;");
request.addProperty("", XML); //now encoded, but server will understand!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using wsimport or a 3rd party library like Axis2 to create the jar client, this client will transform your beans into a well formed XML Request easily.

**Construct client using wsimport:**

Before start, you can find wsimport tool in the $JDK/bin folder.

```
 wsimport -keep -verbose https://www.url.com/xxx/xxx.asmx?wsdl
```

**Construct client using Axis2.**
Example from [site](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html):

> The short story:
>
> 1. Download and unpack the Apache Axis2 Standard Distribution, if you have not done it already.
> 2. Create the client stub with the following command (Assuming that you have Axis2UserGuide.wsdl file on your current working directory):
>
> `%AXIS2_HOME%\bin\WSDL2Java -uri Axis2UserGuide.wsdl -p org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide -d adb -s`
>
> 3. Create the client (for example, Client.java), a Java application that uses the generated stub, and save it in the org/apache/axis2/axis2userguide directory.
> 4. Build the client by typing: ant jar.client.
> 5. Assuming you have a corresponding service, run the client by adding the generated Axis2UserGuideService-test-client.jar file located in build/lib to the classpath and type: java org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide.Client